# How to import bootstrap scss avoiding replication of heading or class statements in the final css?

Tags: css, sass, web-compiler

I'm trying to compile a simple SCSS file for bootsrap customization. Following some guidelines I imported the original bootrap SCSS and added some changes.
The compiler is "web compiler", a Visual Studio extension.
This is the SCSS file used as origin:

```
$primary: #07689F;
$secondary: #c0dae9;
$success: #0ed663;
$info: #A2D5F2;
$warning: #ffd166;
$danger: #f1293e;
$light: #e0e0e0;
$dark: #4e4e4e;

@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

body {
    font-family: Poppins;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

What I see in the final result is that my directives are not implemented within the original bootstrap SCSS file declarations with an override as a result in the CSS. Rather they are simply added at the end of the file as extra directives.

This is the CSS result:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.3.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2019 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #07689F;
  --secondary: #c0dae9;
  --success: #0ed663;
  --info: #A2D5F2;
  --warning: #ffd166;
  --danger: #f1293e;
  --light: #e0e0e0;
  --dark: #4e4e4e;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue",         Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace; }

//[... other things ...]

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto     Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff; }

[tabindex="-1"]:focus {
  outline: 0 !important; }

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem; }

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }

//[...then, at the end of CSS file...]

body {
  font-family: Poppins; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px; }
```

I don't like this very much, I'd like to see the two things integrated. 
Is there a way to get it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say that's how it works. Why do you want it to be inside the same body{}?

Comment: Because if I change something, for example p->margin-top in the wrong place (the first one) it won't work until I realize there is a second statement at the bottom.
In the long run I might have problems with repetitions. Consider that what I've entered is just a small example and the repetitions may increase dramatically. I would have preferred a smart compilation that would have replaced the declared fields that now are twice.

Comment: That's how CSS cascade works. If you run into that problem you might rethink your html/CSS structure. OOCSS or BEM might be the thing you're looking for

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thank you.